# Unable to get project details as part of release pipeline definition api request

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-rest-api

As part of below release pipeline definition api response, I am unable to get the current project details. The "projectReference" is being returned as null every time. Can someone guide me if I am missing anything here.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/definitions/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

Comment: What API call are you making? Are you including $expand? Why do you need the projectReference in the first place? You have the project details already; you need them in order to construct the API call.

Comment: @Mohan Sairam Not get your latest information, is the answer helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0):

From the api document, we can see that "projectReference" contains the id and name information of the project

[image]

If you want to get the project information where the release pipeline is located, you can get the project name from the request url and the project id in the "url" parameter.

```
GET https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{projectName}/_apis/release/definitions?api-version=5.1
```

[image]

If you want to get the project information of the artifact source in the release pipeline, you need to add `$expand=Artifacts` to the request url , so you will get the project id and name of the artifact.

```
GET https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/definitions?$expand=Artifacts&api-version=5.1
```

[image]